# Обработчик сигналов как член класса

Tags: c++, callback

Пишу класс работающий с трафиком RS485 порта.
При открытии порта я указываю функцию, вызываемую при наличии во входном буфере порта каких-то данных:

```
struct sigaction saio; /* definition of signal action */
fd = open(device, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NONBLOCK); /* open the device to be non-blocking (read will return immediatly) */
if (fd <0) { perror(device);}
sigemptyset(&saio.sa_mask); /* install the signal handler before making the device asynchronous */
saio.sa_handler = signal_handler_IO;
```

Если функция - обработчик описана как обучная функция:

```
void signal_handler_IO (int status){
    if (read(fd,&buf,1)){
        std::cout << "I'm recieve byte\t" << std::hex << buf[0] << std::dec << std::endl;
    }
}
```

То проблем нет. Но если я эту функцию делаю членом класса, то возникают ошибки компиляции.

```
error: cannot convert ‘Rs485::signal_handler_IO’ from type ‘void (Rs485::)(int)’ to type ‘__sighandler_t {aka void (*)(int)}’
```

Я в C++ не очень силен и не понимаю что от меня хочет компилятор.
Скажите пожалуйста, как мне сделать членом класса функцию-обработчик ?

Comment: *Нестатическая* функция-член класса всегда получает лишний аргумент - объект класса, для которого она вызвана.  Как компилятору узнать, для какого именно объекта нужно вызывать обработчик? А вам - соответственно, вопрос: что такого в вашем обработчике, что ему нужен некоторый объект класса? Он точно нужен? **Зачем** вы делаете обработчик членом класса? Какую цель вы хотите этим достичь?

Comment: Цель единственная - спрятать функции и данные внутри класса

Comment: Тогда сделайте ее **статической** функцией-членом, и всё.

Comment: Делаю статической, тогда опять ошибка компиляции: error: cannot declare member function ‘static void Rs485::signal_handler_IO(int)’ to have static linkage [-fpermissive]

Comment: Как именно вы ее определяете? Например, не так - в классе объявление, определение вне класса, но все равно со словом `static`? (первое, что в голову приходит, глядя на ошибку)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, sa_handler имеет тип `void (*)(int)`, поэтому сделать можно будет не много.

Это либо стандартная функция, как в C,

```
void handler(int);
saio.sa_handler = &handler;
```

, либо анонимная функция без свободных переменных (начинающаяся с `[]`)

```
saio.sa_handler = [](int sig){ /* ... */ };
```

, либо статический член класса

```
struct Saio {
    static void handler(int sig) { /* ... */ }
};
saio.sa_handler = &Saio::handler;
```

. При этом все три могут принимать лишь один аргумент типа `int`, а о контексте (инкапсулированном в объекте-обработчике состоянии) никто и не подумал.

Ну то есть все данные, нужные обработчику, либо предполагаются глобальными

```
std::ostream &os = std::cout;
struct Saio {
    static void handler(int sig) { os << "Signal #" << sig << std::endl; }
};
```

, либо во всяком случае статическими на уровне класса (Александреску пишет, что это и есть Monostate pattern):

```
class Saio {
    static int handlerData;
    static std::string moreHandlerData() { return "Hello" };
public:
    static void setData(int x) { handlerData = x; }
    static void handler(int sig) {
        os << moreHandlerData()
           << ", this is handler#" << handlerData << " speaking, I've got signal"
           << sig << std::endl;
    }
};
int Saio::handlerData = 42;
```

Comment: В более-менее серьезной программе писать в stream  (в т.ч. и использовать `fprintf()` и т.п.) нельзя (`write()` можно). Вообще, в обработчике можно использовать только [signal safty functions](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html)

Comment: Да, к сожалению, это не более-менее серьезная программа.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Сделал статический член класса, работает как надо.